# Deprecated: strpos(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of type string is deprecated

Tags: php, deprecated, strpos

We are using the following functions for an Invoice Module:

```
    /* Functions: Before */
    function before ($here, $inthat){
        return substr($inthat, 0, strpos($inthat, $here));
    }
    /* Functions: After */
    function after ($here, $inthat){
        if (!is_bool(strpos($inthat, $here)))
        return substr($inthat, strpos($inthat,$here)+strlen($here));
    }   
    /* Functions: Between */
    function between ($here, $that, $inthat){
        return before ($that, after($here, $inthat));
    }
```

This code is showing following Error Message in PHP 8.1:

> Deprecated: strpos(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of type
> string is deprecated

Please guide us as to what to do in this regard.

Thanks,

Lakshmanan

Comment: Don't pass null. As the message said.

Comment: One thing to note is that it's possible that `after()` doesn't actually return anything.  The only return is under the `if` condition.

Comment: Which of the 3 functions is throwing the error? And I'm struggling to see what you're trying to achieve with this code.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Although the title is similar, neither the details of the question nor the answers on that page have much in common with this one.

Comment: PLease put your error message in the question and not the title.

Comment: @NigelRen if PHP gets to the end of a function without explicitly returning anything, then it returns null by default.

Comment: @RobertWent - returning null and returning nothing in most cases would be the same thing.  Especially as these are generally returning strings, returning '' would also be the same as nothing (without the pedantic that null != '').

Answer (score 1):

Error Messages are shown for the following code:

```
return substr($inthat, 0, strpos($inthat, $here));
```

We are getting the following Error Messages:

> Deprecated: strpos(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of
> type string is deprecated in /home/XXX/functions_general.php on line
> 10
> Deprecated: substr(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of
> type string is deprecated in /home/XXX/functions_general.php on line
> 10

We post the following Comments [showing only short example] in the Online Order [osCommerce earlier and Zen Cart now]:

> Invoice No. TI-220013   |
> Invoice Date: 12-Oct-2022   |

We capture these values through the following code:

```
if ($invoice_details != null) {
    $invoice_number = between('Invoice No. ', '|', $invoice_details);
    $invoice_number = trim($invoice_number);
    $invoiced_date = between('Invoice Date: ', '|', $invoice_details);
    $invoiced_date = trim($invoiced_date);
}
```

All the values are shown correctly in spite of the Error Messages.

We have hidden Error Messages by changing the above code as follows:

```
return @substr($inthat, 0, strpos($inthat, $here));
```

Any other suggestion is welcome.

Thanks,

Lakshmanan

Comment: SO is a Q&A site, not a forum. Only replies that answer the question should be posted as answers. Other posts should be made as either comments to answers, edits to the original question, or new questions. You can always comment within your own question, and on others when you have 50 reputation. If you haven't yet read the FAQs (start with the link at the top of the page) and formatting help (click the orange question mark in the post text editing toolbar), do so now.

Comment: place is_string check before strpos